# How to locate existing ("parent") record and add an associated record to it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am scraping a website and basically, I have a table called `games` and a table called `publisher`. A game `has_one :publisher`.

When I find a game, say, Starcraft (with publisher Blizzard), I create a game with title Starcraft, and a publisher with name Blizzard. The problem this:

When I find another game by Blizzard, say Diablo, I create a new game with title `Diablo` and new publisher with name `Blizzard`. Now I have two publishers with name `Blizzard`. How can I ensure that both Starcraft and Diablo both point to the one and only Blizzard?

I though of searching through the database before creating a game, finding if a publisher exists and using that, and if it doesn't exist then create one and then use it. But is this the normal/best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Uniqueness validations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you find it first and if it does not exist, then create it:

```
publisher = Publisher.find_or_create_by_name name: "Blizzard"
publisher.games.build name: "Diablo", <more_params_for_game>
publisher.save

or we could also use create instead of build above.
```

Comment: Yes, but adding an index with `unique => true` would also help to ensure the uniqueness

Comment: @Ismael Abreu, not sure that is applicable here? Some sample code would help.

Comment: `add_index :publishers, :name, :unique => true` will ensure there is no more then 1 publisher with the same name, so if you do `Publisher.create(name: "Blizzard")` twice, the second time you will get an error, so you know something is wrong. And also will improve performance. So he totally should add this to a migration.

Comment: Yes, and you will get an error the second time and thus you won't be able to locate the correct publisher to add the game to. Also, I think the title of the question is inaccurate - the original title was changed when I answered.

Comment: Thanks - But what if I have a set # of publishers that I already created and I am never going to add more publisher, just work with the ones i already have in DB. Kind of like constants. Is there a built in way to work with this type of contants to avoid a find_or_create_by_name query every time a game is added?

Comment: If things are *really* that constant in your app, then you could save the primary key id's of the publisher records in some data structure by doing a find once - when the app starts. Then, to create a new game for a publisher: `Game.create name: "Something", publisher_id: <some id we saved earlier>`.